# Visual studio 2008 Qt Project configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, dll

I am trying to configure my dll project so that I can access QtCore4.dll and QtGui4.dll functions.

In my project properties under c/c++, Additional Include Directories I have added ...\Qt\4.6.0;

project properties under Linker Additional library directories I have added Qt\4.6.0\lib

Right, so what #include  do I need to put in my header files so that I can get the functionality?

Before I was using dependencies and using the includes  and  but now I have removed the dependencies I am getting a 'cannot open file: 'QtCore/qcoreapplication.h': no such file or directory error.

This project is making me feel like a moron.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your additional Include directory should be ..\qt\4.6.0\include. If you use qmake or the VS plugin all this is done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself time and hassle, get the plugin: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

Comment: I got the plugin and installed it, it hasn't helped in my problem though

Comment: You'll need to create a new project that's a "Qt" project after configuring the plugin through "Qt->Qt Options".  Then when you create new Qt classes (anything you want to use Q_OBJECT in) you'll want to add new class rather than file and pick QtClass or QtUiClass.  This will set up the MOC prebuild steps and junk.